# Views are not shown properly inside ScrollView with RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to achieve this...
[image: Big Screen] [image: Small Screen]

Ok this looks good no problem..BUT
here's the problem, if this is on small screen then last view is not showing properly when scrolling to the end of screen.
I've tried to achieve this with `RelativeLayout` and `ConstraintLayout` but effects are same..

[image]

**XML Source Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#959494"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_12sdp">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/box1"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Box 1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/box2"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/box1"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Box 2"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/box3"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/box2"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Box 3"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/box3"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            tools:text="This is a Textview" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#959494"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_12sdp">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/box1"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Box 1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/box2"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Box 2"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/box3"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Box 3"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box3"
            tools:text="This is a Textview" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: The bottom _TextView_ is constrained to the bottom of "Box 3" and the bottom of the parent. That means, for _ConstraintLayout_, that it will be centered between the top view and the bottom of the parent. If you want it to appear at the bottom of that space then you will have to specify `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"` for the bottom view. Otherwise, it is not clear to me exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Here Try This, It Should Work and let me know if it works or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#959494"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_12sdp">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/box1"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Box 1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/box2"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Box 2"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/box3"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Box 3"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box3"
            tools:text="This is a Textview" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I guess not...
All views are aligned centered

Comment: yes, but it's not required you can align them where ever you want. Just be sure to constrain them from all sides.

Comment: above your answer is not working...

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer** BUT to clear some points and for cleanness, I have to post it as an answer...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#959494"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/_12sdp">
    
            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/box1"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Box 1"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    
            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/box2"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/box1">
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Box 2"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    
            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/box3"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/box2">
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Box 3"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box3"
                tools:text="This is a Textview" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

If you look at the above code this is working fine for small screens BUT on large screens, the last view is just adjusted its position to the center of the Box 3 view and end of the screen BUT what I want is to end of the screen.
We can achieve this by changing `textView1` height to 0dp but then the results went opposite like working on a bigger screen only and hiding the last view on the small screen.
[image: Small Screen] [image: Big Screen]

And When setting `textView1` height to 0dp.. results are the opposite as I said.
[image: small screen] [image: bigger screen]

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me using `constraint layout vertical bias`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#959494"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/_12sdp">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/box1"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Box 1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/box2"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/box1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Box 2"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/box3"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/box2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Box 3"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box3"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:text="This is a Textview" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image] [image: small screen]